# How to change size of all inputs?

Tags: stylesheet, input

I would like to change the font size of inputs and outputs. I see that I can just click on options of every single input and set the size, but I don't want to do this separately for every line. Could someone help me find options to do it?

Edit:

I discovered that I can check one Input cell with <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to resize it, too.

Comment: Related: [(14536)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14536/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the `StyleSheet` to change the font sizes of `"Input"` and `"Output"` cells. Adapting @MichaelE2's answer in this related Q/A: [Change font of formula number in DisplayFormulaNumbered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59638/125)

[image]

Comment: Looks great! But maybe you know, what is the reason that it changes size only in newcreated cells? These which was created before changing size are still the same.. On demonstration is works fine

Comment: What application do you use for these screen recordings?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, i use [LICEcap](http://licecap.en.softonic.com/).

Comment: @adolzi, the changes apply to _all_ (previously created _and_ new) `"Input" and `"Output"` cells.