# Old Eyes Need Larger Font

Tags: front-end, customization

How can I permanently change the font size that is used for input.  I would love to have a 12 or 14 point font available.

Comment: See also [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83996/how-to-change-size-of-whole-input?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 6):

A purely programmatic way to change the default magnification for the Notebooks:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, Magnification -> 1.5]
```

or equivalently

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, Magnification] = 1.5;
```

In version 11 the default font used by the FrontEnd [is changed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123736/280). If you prefer "Courier New" as it was in the previous versions, you can use new-in-version 11 undocumented `StyleHints` option:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, StyleHints -> {"CodeFont" -> "Courier"}]
```

or equivalently

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {StyleHints, "CodeFont"}] = "Courier";
```

Comment: As noted [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123823), Consolas is the default only for Windows systems.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, I have changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

> `Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Open Option Inspector`

In **Formatting Options**, find **Font Options** entry. There you will find **FontSize** which is set to `12` by *default*. You can change it to any other number.

Comment: This does work with version 8.0.4 but with versions 10.4.1 and 11.0.0 changing of `FontSize` has no effect.

Comment: This is not ideal, you would want to address FontSize from a notebook's/your default stylesheet to account for all the specific styles.

Answer (score 6):

To set the default magnification for a notebook:

> Preferences -> Advanced -> Notebook Options -> Display Options -> Magnification

then double click slowly on the "value" until it highlights blue and then you can type a default value corresponding to 100%

[image]

The font on my computer was originally set for fighter pilots or eagles:)

Answer (score 2):

Preferences > Advanced > Open Option Inspector > Notebook Options > Display Options > Magnification

Comment: Works great.  Just what I needed